# Sum of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(\frac{1}{2^n})\cos(\frac{3}{2^n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can we get  sum of this series? $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(\frac{1}{2^n})\cos(\frac{3}{2^n})$$

I think we must apply this theorem.

> if in  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}$, $a_n = b_{n+1}-b_n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = b$; $ \implies $ $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}=b-b_1$

But how?

Comment: First apply $\sin x\cos y=\big(\sin(x+y)+\sin(x-y)\big)/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity $\sin x\cos 3x=\frac{1}{2}(\sin 4x-\sin 2x)$ gives$$\sum_{n\ge 1}\sin\frac{1}{2^n}\cos\frac{4}{2^n}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\ge 1}(\sin\frac{4}{2^n}-\sin\frac{2}{2^n})=\frac{1}{2}\sin 2.$$

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
Use identity 
$$\sin a\cos b=\dfrac12(\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b))$$
and then telescopic property of series.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Compute first $\;\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin \frac{1}{2^n}\, \cos \frac{3}{2^n}$ and use the linearisation formula
$$2\sin a \,\cos b=\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b).$$